# parsing white spaces in front of `elem` method

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I tried to parse an input of two Ints and some elements and the end:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class X extends JavaTokenParsers {
  lazy val elems = elem("wrong elem", "#WB-" contains _)
  lazy val lists = repsep(rep(elems), ",")
  lazy val p1 = int ~ int ~ lists
  lazy val p2 = int ~ int ~ (whiteSpace ~> lists)

  def go[A](p: Parser[A]) = parseAll(p, "1 2   WB#,---,BBB") match {
    case NoSuccess(msg, _) => sys.error(msg)
    case _ =>
  }

  lazy val int: Parser[Int] =
    wholeNumber ^^ {
      try _.toInt catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException => sys.error("invalid number")
      }
    }
}
```

An example input is given in method `go`. The Ints and the elements at the end have to be delimited by spaces. But this works only for the Ints and not for the elements. When I type in

```
val x = new X
x go x.p1
```

I get following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: string matching regex `\z' expected but `W' found
```

But when I type in

```
x go x.p1
```

I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: string matching regex `\s+' expected but `W' found
```

At the end I want to have a `Parser[Int ~ Int ~ List[List[Char]]]`. Why does inserting white spaces in front of `elem` not work? And how can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace elems by a RegEx Parser :

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class X extends JavaTokenParsers {

lazy val elems = "[#WB-]".r
lazy val lists = repsep(rep(elems), ",")
lazy val p1 = int ~ int ~ lists

def go[A](p: Parser[A]) = parseAll(p, "1 2   WB#,---,BBB") match {
case NoSuccess(msg, _) => sys.error(msg)
case _ =>
}

lazy val int: Parser[Int] =
wholeNumber ^^ {
try _.toInt catch {
    case e: NumberFormatException => sys.error("invalid number")
  }
}
}
```

i have removed p2 because is not useful now

Comment: Thanks, `spaces` works as expected. But why does it not work when it is `whiteSpace`?

Comment: I never use whiteSpace directly ( the default value for it is a regex expression = [\s]+) and it's used by the parser to automatically skip whitespace ( you can disable it by override the skipWhiteSpace   override val skipWhitespace = false)

Comment: I know what `whiteSpace` does and how it is defined. But I don't understand why it results in an error when used explicitly. Why doesn't it stop when it can't read the input any more and go forward to the next parser?

Comment: Antoras, i think the problem is on the definition of elems, the parser try to parse all string "WB#,---,BBB"" with elems but it failed because the string is not contained by "#WB-" and after that the parser try to parse the first char ( 'W' )  with a whiteSpace, that why you have this error ( string matching regex `\s+' expected but `W' found)

Comment: I refine my answer to take this into account, so you will only need the p1 parser

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thanks for your help.